# VMware ESXi/vSphere Fault Tolerance vCPU Limit

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, fault-tolerance, vcpu

So I am aware that VMs in FT mode are limited to a single vCPU. Is it possible to assign multiple cores to the single vCPU, and still have the VM support FT mode? Or are you forced to use both a vCPU and single vCore per FT VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot. VMware only supports a single core on a FT VM. [This](https://communities.vmware.com/people/vmroyale/blog/2009/05/18/vmware-fault-tolerance-requirements-and-limitations) site has a good reference.

That said, VMware FT has a whole host of limitations. You'd be better off utilizing your application/OS failover methods.